# How to do the equivalent of 'distinct' on array field in BQ?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Let's take the following data:

[image]

It can also be generated in BQ with the following statement:

```
with x as (
    select 1 as RowID, DATE('2014-01-01') as Date, [200, 300] as Payments, ["Contractor", "Monday"] as Tags union all
    select 2 as RowID, DATE('2014-01-02') as Date, [100, 200, 200, 200, 700] as Payments, ["Contractor", "Bi-Weekly"] as Tags
)
select * from x
```

How would I do the following two 'distinct' totals on the right of the following:

[image]

That is, I want to get a "total" that doesn't double-count, or rather, only gets the distinct items based on the RowID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it is the total row that you really care about.  You can calculate the first two columns by unnesting both tags and payments in parallel.

Then for the total, unnest the payments without the tags:

```
with x as (
      select 1 as RowID, DATE('2014-01-01') as Date, [200, 300] as Payments, ["Contractor", "Monday"] as Tags union all
      select 2 as RowID, DATE('2014-01-02') as Date, [100, 200, 200, 200, 700] as Payments, ["Contractor", "Bi-Weekly"] as Tags
     )
select tag, count(*), sum(payment)
from x cross join
     unnest(x.payments) payment cross join
     unnest(x.tags) tag
group by 1
union all 
select 'Total', count(*), sum(payment)
from x cross join
      unnest(x.payments) payment;
```

Comment: beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. Is the above a common way to query on arrays? I always debate whether the proper way is to 'double count' or to do a total that gets the actual counts/totals on the original data set. Is there a more 'correct' way to do it?

Comment: @David542. . . This gets the counts that you intend.  I don't think there is a simpler method than this.

Comment: right I mean is this a common approach to doing bi-related stuff with arrays? or is it usually double-counted?

Comment: I suppose a better way to ask is if you were to see a "Total" for Payments would you expect to see `$1900` or `$3800`? Or does it depend more on the circumstance and either one might be preferable at different times?

Comment: `I don't think there is a simpler method than this.` -  I think my answer presents much simpler approach :o)

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select tag, sum(payment) amount_paid, count(payment) payments_count 
from data, unnest(tags || ['Total']) tag, unnest(payments) payment
group by tag
```

if applied to sample data in your  question - output is

[image]

Comment: awesome! Add in a `order by (tag='total')` so it's easier to read though with the Totals at the bottom.

Comment: have you seen a time where someone would ever want the total to be `3800` instead of what you have above when working with any clients? Or is the `1900` the 'correct' answer if anyone is ever working with arrays?

Comment: From my experience - expected total is 1900. Never seen practical case where 3800 would be expected